AJAX calls based on dropdown selection
I need to fetch the data for a drop down control from the server. Then I need to fetch more data based on what I select in the drop down.
Could somebody explain it by using AJAX, something like this:
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#journalDropdown').change(function () {
    var journalId = $(this).val();
    if (journalId) {
      $.getJSON('/Order/GetProducts', { journalId: journalId }, function (data) {
        var productDropdown = $('#productDropdown');
        productDropdown.empty();
        productDropdown.append('<option value="">Select Product</option>');

        $.each(data, function (i, product) {
          productDropdown.append('<option value="' + product.id + '">' + product.name + '</option>');
        });
      });
    } else {
      $('#productDropdown').empty().append('<option value="">Select Product</option>');
      $('#priceInput').val('');
    }
  });
});


I don't understand what the goal of your question is, given that the code is already doing what you ask...?

"I need to fetch the data for a drop down control from the server." you didn't specify which url and parameters

If you want to know how to build a cascade dropdown ajax in asp.net core MVC, I suggest you could follow below example.
Firstly, you could create the two model and have relationship with it.
Like below:
public class Journal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int JournalId { get; set; }   
}

Then you could firstly return the Journal to the view and write another post method inside the controller to accept the JournalId and select product to the client.
Controller method like below:
    // show the Journal
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        //you could also query the data from the database
        var journals =new List<Journal> {new Journal { Id=1, Name="test1"}, new Journal { Id=2,Name="test2"} };
        return View(journals);
    }

    // Action to get products based on the selected journal
    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetProducts(int journalId)
    {
        //you could also query the data from the database
        var products = new List<Product> { new Product { Id=1, Name="product1" , JournalId=1 }
        , new Product { Id = 2, Name = "product2", JournalId = 1 }
        , new Product { Id = 3, Name = "product3", JournalId = 2 }
        }; 

        var productresult = products.Where(p => p.JournalId == journalId).ToList();
        return Json(products);
    }

Then inside the view, you could firstly load the journals dropdown and generate the second dropdown based on the select result of the journals dropdown.
@model IEnumerable<Journal>
<div>
    <label for="journalDropdown">Journal:</label>
    <select id="journalDropdown">
        <option value="">Select Journal</option>
        @foreach (var journal in Model)
        {
            <option value="@journal.Id">@journal.Name</option>
        }
    </select>
</div>

<div>
    <label for="productDropdown">Product:</label>
    <select id="productDropdown">
        <option value="">Select Product</option>
    </select>
</div>


@section Scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#journalDropdown').change(function () {
                var journalId = $(this).val();
                if (journalId) {
                    $.getJSON('/Home/GetProducts', { journalId: journalId }, function (data) {
                        var productDropdown = $('#productDropdown');
                        productDropdown.empty();
                        productDropdown.append('<option value="">Select Product</option>');

                        $.each(data, function (i, product) {
                            productDropdown.append('<option value="' + product.id + '">' + product.name + '</option>');
                        });
                    });
                } else {
                    $('#productDropdown').empty().append('<option value="">Select Product</option>');
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}

Result:

